# Im using Bootstrap 5. Is there a way to move the elements inside a div without using padding or margin?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.104.2" />
    <title>Features</title>

    <link href="assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }

      .b-example-divider {
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-width: 1px 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
          inset 0 0.125em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      }

      .b-example-vr {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .bi {
        vertical-align: -0.125em;
        fill: currentColor;
      }

      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="features.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center">
    <div class="container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <header class="mb-auto">
        <div>
          <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0 featuresheader">Features</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
            <a
              class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active"
              aria-current="page"
              href="index.html"
              >Home</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="features.html"
              >Features</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main>
        <div class="features1">
          <div class="">
            <h1 class="features2">Features</h1>
            <p class="lead features3">The features below are still in beta</p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-device shadow-sm d-none d-md-block"></div>
          <div
            class="product-device product-device-2 shadow-sm d-none d-md-block"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */

body {
  text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url();
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
}

/*
 * Header
 */

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  color: #00ff7f;
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
}

.featuresheader {
  cursor: default;
  color: white;
}

/*
 * Lines inside of the features div
 */

.product-device {
  /* position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: -30%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 540px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 21px;
  transform: rotate(30deg); */
}

.product-device::before {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10px;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px; */
}

.product-device-2 {
  /* top: -25%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; */
}

/*
 * Extra Utilities
 */
.flex-equal > * {
  flex: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-md-equal > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*
 * text related to features
 */
.features1 {
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}

.features2 {
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

.features3 {
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

/*
 * Bootstrap Icon settings
 */

.feature-icon {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

.icon-link > .bi {
  margin-top: 0.125rem;
  margin-left: 0.125rem;
  fill: currentcolor;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.icon-link:hover > .bi {
  transform: translate(0.25rem);
}

.icon-square {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

/*
 * Text shadow for cards
 */
.text-shadow-1 {
  text-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.text-shadow-2 {
  text-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.text-shadow-3 {
  text-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

/*
 * Image for cards
 */

.card-cover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*
 * Icon settings
 */

.feature-icon-small {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

The problem is I have a class in my css named .features1 with padding-bottom: 500px; I can not put anything below that because it just makes extra white space and doesn't work at all. My guess would be because it is pushing everything down. Is there anyway I can make the features h1 and everything inside of that whole div move up without using padding or margin? I want to put something underneath it without having it make extra white space below and not work. Thank you.

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJ0M.png)

I tried using Bootstraps built in elements like, py, mx, pb and col. I expected it to move up without taking up space below it but nothing happened. Im not sure if it was used right.

Comment: Don't use large pixels in Bootstrap (e.g. `500px`); it's because 500px occupies quite a lot of space in small screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform: translate property, but I would advise to just reconstruct the layout so it fits without such shenanigans